# Running Get-SPWeb in powershell command for sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to run the following code against sharepoint.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Variables for Web URL, List Name
$WebURL ="https://sharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/Sharepoint"
 
#get the list object
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
 
# Check if web has Unique permission - Root webs always uses Unique permission
if ( ($web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) -and ($web.IsRootWeb -eq $false ) )
 {
      #Reset broken inheritance
      $web.ResetRoleInheritance()
      Write-host "Broken Inheritance Reset on web:" $web.URL
 }
```

When I try to run this command I get: Get-SPWeb : The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

When I try to add the snapin, Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell I get: Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.

I've tried installing the snap-in and I've tried using Sharepoint Online Management Shell, I've tried ISE and that doesn't appear to work either.  Am I just missing something?

Comment: What version/type of SharePoint are you trying to target? OnLine or On-Premises?

Comment: Online, we do not have on-premises sharepoint.

Comment: Ah, that's your problem then. The module/snap-in is for on-premises and so is your code. You need to use the online module and online cmdlts or event better: PnP for PowerShell. :)

Comment: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online